# compile FFTW fortran program

Tags: bash, compilation, fortran, fftw

I'm quite new to Unix and bash systems, therefore i'm sorry in advance if the question might look stupid.

I've recently downloaded and installed the FFTW program on my iMac (following the guidelines in chapter 10 of http://www.fftw.org/fftw3.pdf). The installation has succeeded as i get no error when i do "make check".

Now i wanted to start writing a small test program using the above mentioned libraries.

The fortran code is very simple (and it is basically just a check of how to link the FFTW libraries to fortran):

```
program fft

use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
include 'fftw3.f03'

implicit none

end program fft
```

however when it comes to compile the program i'm completely clueless (basically because i'm not expert at all in compiling) what i typically do to compile is:

```
gfortran -o "executable_ename"  "main.f90"
```

However this is not working, in particular i get the following error:

```
 fft.f90:4: Error: Can't open included file 'fftw3.f03'
```

If you could give me a hand with this problem, and maybe also explain what i'm missing and why it would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify where `fftw3.f03` is located! On my machine, it is in `/usr/include`, so I use:

```
gfortran -I/usr/include -o "executable_ename" main.f90
```

BTW: the `implicit none` must go in front of the `include`:

```
program fft
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
  implicit none

  include 'fftw3.f03'
end program fft
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the file fftw3.f03 on my machine has the same location as yours. However when i try to compile using your string i keep getting the same error. Is there a way to get the path of the folder inside the terminal?

Comment: Got it, the correct directory was gfortran -I/usr/local/include -o "executable_ename" main.f90

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that the directory which contains fftw03.f03 is in the compiler's search list for include files.

Locate that directory (let's say it is in /foo/bar), then use

```
gfortran -I /foo/bar -o executable_name main.f90
```

Comment: Not knowing what is in fftw03.f03, it might also be dangerous to put implicit none after it.  I haven't looked at the docs, though.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'm commenti under Alexander Vogt answer, he suggested to put the include after implicit none statement too.